# Bluetooth LE devices connection order

Tags: linux, gentoo, bluetooth, bluez

Running **Gentoo linux** distribution with **kernel 4.9.16** and **bluez 5.43**
Have two devices: **Logitech MX Anywhere 2** mouse and **Logitech K780** keyboard
Both devices are Bluetooth 4.0 LE.
Bluetooth adapter is built into wireless card: **Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 8260**

I have faced an extremely interesting use case.
`sspmode` is enabled for bluetooth adapter.
Both devices are pairing and working very well separately.

After reboot, sleep or just disconnecting and connecting devices back I observed the following:

1. Connecting keyboard first and it works well.
   Connect mouse afterwards and both devices are playing nicely and don't have any issues.
2. Connecting mouse first and it also works well.
   Connecting keyboard afterwards and it claims to be in `connected` according to `bluetoothctl` and `blueberry` applet, but typing does not work.

Monitoring via `udevadm monitor` in both cases revealed following:

#### For keyboard first:

```
KERNEL[9704.383752] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:3585 (bluetooth)
ACTION=add
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:3585
DEVTYPE=link
SEQNUM=2576
SUBSYSTEM=bluetooth

KERNEL[9708.085453] add      /devices/virtual/misc/uhid/0005:046D:B33B.0009 (hid)
ACTION=add
DEVPATH=/devices/virtual/misc/uhid/0005:046D:B33B.0009
HID_ID=0005:0000046D:0000B33B
HID_NAME=Keyboard K780
HID_PHYS=XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
HID_UNIQ=XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
MODALIAS=hid:b0005g0001v0000046Dp0000B33B
SEQNUM=2577
SUBSYSTEM=hid

KERNEL[9708.085644] add      /devices/virtual/misc/uhid/0005:046D:B33B.0009/input/input22 (input)
ABS=100000000
ACTION=add
DEVPATH=/devices/virtual/misc/uhid/0005:046D:B33B.0009/input/input22
EV=12001f
KEY=3007f 0 0 483ffff17aff32d bf54444600000000 1 130f938b17c007 ffe77bfad941dfff febeffdfffefffff fffffffffffffffe
LED=1f
MODALIAS=input:b0005v046DpB33Be0018-e0,1,2,3,4,11,14,k71,72,73,74,75,77,79,7A,7B,7C,7D,7E,7F,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,8A,8B,8C,8E,8F,90,96,98,9B,9C,9E,9F,A1,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7,A8,A9,AB,AC,AD,AE,B0,B1,B2,B5,B6,B7,B8,B9,BA,BB,BC,BD,BE,BF,C0,C1,C2,CE,CF,D0,D1,D2,D4,D8,D9,DB,DF,E0,E1,E4,E7,E8,E9,EA,EB,F0,F1,F4,100,161,162,166,16A,16E,172,174,176,178,179,17A,17B,17C,17D,17F,180,182,183,185,188,189,18C,18D,18E,18F,190,191,192,193,195,197,198,199,19A,19C,1A0,1A1,1A2,1A3,1A4,1A5,1A6,1A7,1A8,1A9,1AA,1AB,1AC,1AD,1AE,1AF,1B0,1B1,1B7,1BA,240,241,242,243,244,245,246,250,251,r6,a20,m4,l0,1,2,3,4,sfw
MSC=10
NAME="Keyboard K780"
PHYS="XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX"
PRODUCT=5/46d/b33b/18
PROP=0
REL=40
SEQNUM=2578
SUBSYSTEM=input
UNIQ="XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX"

KERNEL[9708.085718] add      /devices/virtual/misc/uhid/0005:046D:B33B.0009/input/input22/event16 (input)
ACTION=add
DEVNAME=/dev/input/event16
DEVPATH=/devices/virtual/misc/uhid/0005:046D:B33B.0009/input/input22/event16
MAJOR=13
MINOR=80
SEQNUM=2579
SUBSYSTEM=input

KERNEL[9708.085741] add      /devices/virtual/misc/uhid/0005:046D:B33B.0009/input/input22/input22::numlock (leds)
ACTION=add
DEVPATH=/devices/virtual/misc/uhid/0005:046D:B33B.0009/input/input22/input22::numlock
SEQNUM=2580
SUBSYSTEM=leds

KERNEL[9708.085757] change   /devices/virtual/misc/uhid/0005:046D:B33B.0009/input/input22/input22::numlock (leds)
ACTION=change
DEVPATH=/devices/virtual/misc/uhid/0005:046D:B33B.0009/input/input22/input22::numlock
SEQNUM=2581
SUBSYSTEM=leds
TRIGGER=kbd-numlock

KERNEL[9708.085772] add      /devices/virtual/misc/uhid/0005:046D:B33B.0009/input/input22/input22::capslock (leds)
ACTION=add
DEVPATH=/devices/virtual/misc/uhid/0005:046D:B33B.0009/input/input22/input22::capslock
SEQNUM=2582
SUBSYSTEM=leds

KERNEL[9708.085787] change   /devices/virtual/misc/uhid/0005:046D:B33B.0009/input/input22/input22::capslock (leds)
ACTION=change
DEVPATH=/devices/virtual/misc/uhid/0005:046D:B33B.0009/input/input22/input22::capslock
SEQNUM=2583
SUBSYSTEM=leds
TRIGGER=kbd-capslock

KERNEL[9708.085801] add      /devices/virtual/misc/uhid/0005:046D:B33B.0009/input/input22/input22::scrolllock (leds)
ACTION=add
DEVPATH=/devices/virtual/misc/uhid/0005:046D:B33B.0009/input/input22/input22::scrolllock
SEQNUM=2584
SUBSYSTEM=leds

KERNEL[9708.085816] change   /devices/virtual/misc/uhid/0005:046D:B33B.0009/input/input22/input22::scrolllock (leds)
ACTION=change
DEVPATH=/devices/virtual/misc/uhid/0005:046D:B33B.0009/input/input22/input22::scrolllock
SEQNUM=2585
SUBSYSTEM=leds
TRIGGER=kbd-scrolllock

KERNEL[9708.085830] add      /devices/virtual/misc/uhid/0005:046D:B33B.0009/input/input22/input22::compose (leds)
ACTION=add
DEVPATH=/devices/virtual/misc/uhid/0005:046D:B33B.0009/input/input22/input22::compose
SEQNUM=2586
SUBSYSTEM=leds

KERNEL[9708.085842] add      /devices/virtual/misc/uhid/0005:046D:B33B.0009/input/input22/input22::kana (leds)
ACTION=add
DEVPATH=/devices/virtual/misc/uhid/0005:046D:B33B.0009/input/input22/input22::kana
SEQNUM=2587
SUBSYSTEM=leds

KERNEL[9708.085857] change   /devices/virtual/misc/uhid/0005:046D:B33B.0009/input/input22/input22::kana (leds)
ACTION=change
DEVPATH=/devices/virtual/misc/uhid/0005:046D:B33B.0009/input/input22/input22::kana
SEQNUM=2588
SUBSYSTEM=leds
TRIGGER=kbd-kanalock

KERNEL[9708.085875] add      /devices/virtual/misc/uhid/0005:046D:B33B.0009/hidraw/hidraw3 (hidraw)
ACTION=add
DEVNAME=/dev/hidraw3
DEVPATH=/devices/virtual/misc/uhid/0005:046D:B33B.0009/hidraw/hidraw3
MAJOR=249
MINOR=3
SEQNUM=2589
SUBSYSTEM=hidraw
```

#### For mouse first

```
KERNEL[9746.385023] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:3586 (bluetooth)
ACTION=add
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:3586
DEVTYPE=link
SEQNUM=2615
SUBSYSTEM=bluetooth
```

As a result it causes a lot of inconvenience if you accidentally touch mouse first keyboard will have no chance to work unless you turn mouse off and turn it on again after keyboard is connected.

Any idea why that can be happening and how to solve that?